# Not able to store the content of URL in a variable string

Tags: java, android

I want to get the content of a URL an show it in Log. But the problem here is this piece of code not storing any data into a string variable **result** in onCreate method and not displaying in the log.

Any suggestions ?

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try{
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();

            while(data!=-1)
            {
                char current = (char) data ;
                result+=result;
                data=reader.read();

            }
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i("Success","Till here worked");
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
    String result=" ";
    Log.i("Success","Till here worked");
    try {
        Log.i("Success","Till here worked");
        result = task.execute("https://www.google.com").get();
        Log.i("Success","Till here worked");
        Log.i("Content of URL : ",result);
        Log.i("Failure","No result before this");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Make sure that you have permission to use internet in your Manifest

Comment: ' <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> ' yeah I have used this in manifest @Kwright02

Comment: I believe your issue could be that you're doing task.execute rather than task.doInBackround

Comment: If there is any edit can you please suggest in answer @Kwright02

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but I thought I should mention there are problems with the way you're reading the content of the web page. The biggest one is that you aren't letting the web page tell you its own character encoding -- you're substituting whatever the default encoding is for your own system. Another problem is that this code is potentially very slow and inefficient for larger web pages since you're reading one character at a time, with no buffering, and using single-character concatenation in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

You missed the behavior of asynchronous execution .`DownloadTask` will start on a separate thread and MainThread will run the code sequentially . So in this way `result` will be null each time .

So do your stuff inside `onPostExecute()` of `AsyncTask`. Read about working of [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                char current = (char) data;
                result += result;
                data = reader.read();

            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (result != null) {
            Log.i("Content of URL : ", result);
            // USe the result for further process here 
        } else {
            Log.i("Failure", "No result");
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DownloadTask task = new DownloadTask();
     task.execute("https://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: Can't I use the onPostExecute method in onCreate ?

Comment: This method is of AsyncTask class .

Comment: How can  I pass the URL of which I need to get content ?

Answer (score 0):

Use volley library to get content from URL.